# Reactstrap Navbar align items right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

as said in the title I'm trying my best to align the items to right side of the navbar
I tried also ml-auto on Nav and mr-auto on items and ml-auto on items. But the reactstrap should stay on the left side. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUZRj.png) As seen on the picture. So I would appreciate help from you guys, I'm kinda new react and web development in general.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  NavbarText,
} from "reactstrap";

const Example = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar color="light" light expand="sm">
        <NavbarBrand href="/" className="mr-auto">
          reactstrap
        </NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={toggle} className="mr-2" />
        <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
          <Nav navbar>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="https://www.google.com">Team</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="https://www.google.com">Events</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
              <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                Unsere Beratung
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu right>
                <DropdownItem>Bipapo</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem>TomLongSchlong</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem divider />
                <DropdownItem>Der coole Reset</DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="https://www.google.com">Social Media</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="https://www.google.com">Kontakt</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: Not sure if there's a specific prop in react strap, but make sure the nav list container is flex and use justify content flex-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just worked for me I hope it will work for you too!

```
className="position-absolute top-0 end-0"
```

Best regards
Bias